# Mysql, how to combine results from join queries?

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

```
Objects
ID | Name
----------
1    name1

Tags
ID | ObjectId | Tag
--------------------
1    1          tag1
2    1          tag2

Attributes
ID | ObjectId | Key | Value
--------------------
1    1          key1  value1  
2    1          key2  value2
```

And I'd like to write a query which would give a single row like:

```
id = 1
name = name1
tags = tag1,tag2
attributes = key1=value1,key2=value2
```

However, this query:

```
SELECT      o.name, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) as tags,
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a,'=',a.value)) as attributes
FROM        objects o 
LEFT JOIN   attributes a on a.ObjectId = o.id
LEFT JOIN   tags t on t.ObjectId = o.id
WHERE       p.id = 1
```

gives me this single row result, with repeated tag/attribute values

```
id = 1
name = name1
tags = tag1,tag1,tag2,tag2
attributes = key1=value1,key2=value2,key1=value1,key2=value2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your solution is that you are joining all related tags against all related attributes, effectively producing a cross join.

Instead, you could use scalar subqueries. For example, you can write it as:

```
select
  id,
  name,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) FROM tags t on t.ObjectId = o.id) as tags,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.key,'=',a.value)) 
     FROM attributes a on a.ObjectId = o.id) as attributes
FROM objects o
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: that works but feels like it could get messy. any thoughts on if I'm better off doing 3 separate queries and mapping it all together in application code?

Comment: What's your concern?

Comment: that using subqueries in this way will produce hard to read/maintain code? (if in actuality i will need many more subqueries)

Comment: It's definitively longer that separate subqueries. Three separate ones could be easier to read. On the flip side, they'll be much slower.

Comment: makes sense. you would recommend subqueries for this implementing this type of aggregation? there aren't aggregation alterantives like `json_agg` or something similar?